# JVM creating Objects on the Stack? (and more)

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, heap-memory

Are there JVMs out there, that create Objects on the stack?
Or JVMs that do not interact with Java Garbage Collection via Reference Counters etc?

Assuming we have a temporary Object created in a method.
And this Object's reference never gets passed/stored/accessed outside the method.
It is just used internally.

When following the classic approach of allocating objects (on the stack, along with reference counters), the following steps would have to be take care of:

1. Find a spot in the Heap that is large enough to hold the Object
2. Allocate the space
3. Update reference pointer
4. Register Object with garbage collection
5. [... object gets used, eventually discarded ...]
6. Identify for Garbage Collection
7. Remove from Heap
8. Unregister from GC

So if now a VM created Objects on the stack, the steps 1,3,4,6,7,8 would not be necessary, and step 2 and its 7ish counterpart would be easy stack management.

So are there JVMs that optimize this?

Or any hybrid systems, like allocating the Object in Heap, but not touching the normal GC, and instead direclty remove the Object at the end of its scope?

Are there implementations with multiple Heaps (one GC-supervised and the other stack-supervised)?

Comment: "Or JVMs that do not interact with Java Garbage Collection via Reference Counters etc?" - java GC is not reference counting

Comment: and if you have object that is never escaping a method than java will probably eliminate allocation, it will not allocate object at all. As JIT can perform such optimization on hot methods.

Comment: Point 4, 7 and 8 do do not exist in any real life JVM. There is no registry (well except for objects with a nontrivial finalizer) and objects don't get "removed". What should removal be? The RAM is still there. In any sophisticated JVM, point 1 doesn't exist either, read about TLABs. They also make point 2 trivial. The only actual issue is point 6. But the garbage collector doesn't run for a single object. It runs for *all* objects, when the memory is full or a threshold has been crossed.

Comment: @GotoFinal when you say 'it will not allocate object at all', do you mean 'not on the Heap, but on the Stack only', or is there a special technique of only using the object's member variables on the Stack? What about further Objects that our said Object references? Do you have any link for me to read?

Comment: @GotoFinal and @Holger you're completely right. I always took it for granted that the JVM used reference counting for lightweight GCing on the side. But having read the details of `Serial Garbage Collector` and `Parallel Garbage Collector` and `CMS Concurrent Mark Sweep` and the new `G1 Garbage First`, I see that they are all  `stop-the-world` or `stop-the-threads` with relatively heavy impact, compared to Reference Counting. So no parallel smalltime-reference counting GC in java.

Comment: "reference counting" is not that lightweight as you might think, like there is pretty big issue with objects referencing each other and then you need to perform some more advanced analytics to find them even if they are no longer used. + just reference counting will end up with fragmented heap that will slowdown app or even waste so much memory app will not be able to work for longer time. And only very small part of such modern GC are stop-the-world, most of the stuff is done in parallel without stopping everything.

Comment: Well, not stopping everything, true, but the respective Threads. "Reference Counting" WOULD actually be easy and lightweight, when you do not rely solely on it. That's what I meant. Your 'two objects referencing each other' while not being reachable by any live thread is a good example that you could ignore in Reference Counting, when you have a second mechanism SGC,PGC,CMS or G1. And (almost) every one of those methods (except the copy collector) hast the problem of fragmentation, and all of those have strategies to fix that, especially the G1. So I assumed it was implemented in JVMs.

Comment: @JayC667 reference counting is far away from being “easy and lightweight”. It requires that all changes to reference variables are performed in a thread safe way, augmented with atomic counter updates. Then, freeing an object when the counter reaches zero doesn’t come for free. It requires maintaining a data structure keeping all these tiny free memory fragments. A copying or compacting garbage collector never maintains such data structures. It only operations in large blocks. Breaking down the overhead to the fraction of a single object would yield *less* overhead than reference counting.

Comment: @Holger True, in the end you would have to start compacting memory spaces anyway, so in runtime performance terms, reference counting would not be that far - if at all - superior to the G1 for example. And in memory terms, reference counting would impose quite some overhead. So I understand now why no one is implementing it parallel to the 4 default GCs. Especially, when the JIT introduces 'object buffers' for objects/references that get allocated and 'de-allocated' a lot, making them stay in the same place, bypassing allocation and 'de-allocation' most of the time. Thanxalot for the insights!

Comment: Well, in memory terms, reference counting can be implemented with less overhead, as the maintenance structures can be placed within the free memory itself. So if you have a system heavily restricted in memory, so that CPU performance is secondary, reclaiming objects as soon as possible using reference counting has a point. But that doesn’t apply to typical desktop and server environments. Not even mobiles are that restricted today…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kinda, there is project called valhalla that aims to provide value types to java, and it can be already download & used, but it is NOT ready for production usage (and if it will be ready, then it will be probably just merged to one of java official releases).
You can download the early access release. You can download the EA release from https://jdk.java.net/valhalla/ and page about feature itself: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169

Additional notes:
Java does not use reference counting, GC works by looking for root objects that are definitely used, like object from currently executed methods, and then finds any other objects that are referenced from these roots, and remove all the rest.

Also JIT perform escape analysis and can remove the need of allocating an object at all, instead will just use the stack to store data that would normally be stored in that object. (note that this is NOT stack allocation, as object is not even created). And thanks to inlining it can also do that cross-methods, but you can't control it or have any guarantee that it will happen.

Comment: Ah okay, so that clears up my question on your comment. Thanx a lot! I'll do some reading there.